# Which font are these numbers made of?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I tried to search online for these texts (with all font ID sites recommended), but couldn't find the correct one, please help me.

I don't have characters, only numbers, that's the hard part:

[image], [image], [image]

Closer look:

[image], [image], [image]

I think this is some basic font, but couldn't figured it out (yet).

Comment: There's no way to accurately identify fonts with such low resolution images. What I would do is head over to a font site, and search through sans serif fonts which are similar. [see example for google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=60%2010%2015&preview.text_type=custom&category=Sans+Serif) and choose one which is similar.

Comment: It puzzles me me that if you only have a few numbers in low resolution, why does it even matter if you can find the exact font?

Comment: @BillyKerr Actually Barlow is a pretty good match.